# Accordion menu JQuery - How to open a specific "id"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu like an appointment book with all months of the year. 
I created a JQuery file to open and close this.

```
 $(function() {
var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
    this.el = el || {};
    this.multiple = multiple || false;

    var links = this.el.find('.link');

    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getMonth();

    var links2 = this.el.find('#mes'+n);

    // Events
    links.on('click',{el: this.el, multiple: this.multiple}, this.dropdown)

    //links2.on('',{el: this.el, multiple: this.multiple}, this.dropdown)

}

Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
    var $el = e.data.el;
        $this = $(this),
        $next = $this.next();

    $next.slideToggle();
    $this.parent().toggleClass('open');


    if (!e.data.multiple) {
        $el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
    };
}   

var accordion = new Accordion($('#accordion'), false);
});
```

The "link" variable find the "div" to open and close when I click the mouse pointer on this. It calls the "dropdown" function.

I tried to create a "link2" variable to call the specific "id". **So how I proceed to do a dropdown in a specific "id" when I enter in the page, without mouse clicks???**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want one of the items to start off expanded. I assume `links2` has class `.link`. You can trigger a click event with `links2.trigger("click");`.

```
var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
    this.el = el || {};
    this.multiple = multiple || false;

    var links = this.el.find('.link');

    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getMonth();

    var links2 = this.el.find('#mes'+n);

    // Events
    links.on('click',{el: this.el, multiple: this.multiple}, this.dropdown)

    links2.trigger("click");
}
```

Comment: @AnthonyTailer In that case, I would very much appreciate it if you can mark this answer as the accepted answer. Thanks.